# Building a complex expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

I am having a problem with extracting a complex number from expression.

For example, suppose a complex expression is given with real and imaginary part as follows:

```
re = 
  1/6 (2 Subscript[f, α1] - Subscript[f, α2] - Subscript[f, α3] + Sqrt[3] (-Subscript[f, β2] + Subscript[f, β3]));
im = 
  1/6 (Sqrt[3] Subscript[f, α2] - Sqrt[3] Subscript[f, α3] + 2 Subscript[f, β1] - Subscript[f, β2] - Subscript[f, β3]);
cpx = re + I*im;
```

All f's are real numbers, and complex numbers are defined with:

```
Subscript[f, αβ1] = Subscript[f, α1] + I*Subscript[f, β1];
Subscript[f, αβ2] = Subscript[f, α2] + I*Subscript[f, β2];
Subscript[f, αβ3] = Subscript[f, α3] + I*Subscript[f, β3];
```

I want to get the complex expression:

```
1/3 (Subscript[f, \[Alpha]\[Beta]1] + E^((2 I \[Pi])/3) Subscript[f, \[Alpha]\[Beta]2] + E^(-((2 I \[Pi])/3)) Subscript[f, \[Alpha]\[Beta]3])
```

I am quite new to Mathematica and after digging through help I could not find a way to do this. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Avoid using `Subscript` until you understand its effects well enough that you don't want to use it ;-)

Comment: Try `1/3*(Subscript[f, αβ1] + Subscript[f, αβ2]*E^(I*2*π/3) + Subscript[f, αβ3]*E^(I*4*π/3))`. Note the capital letter `E` for Euler's $e$.

Comment: Thanks, completely overlooked Euler's E. However, this still does not solve my problem. I want Mathematica to produce the final expression:
`1/3*(Subscript[f, αβ1] + Subscript[f, αβ2]*E^(I*2*π/3) + Subscript[f, αβ3]*E^(I*4*π/3))`
Of course,  this is just a convenient example.

Comment: I don't understand:"do not use `Subscript`". This all can be rewritten without them. Is that relevant here? Thanks!

Comment: `fα1`, if undefined, represents an unknown **number** to _Mathematica's_ algebraic machinery, but `Subscript[f, αβ1]` represents an undefined **expression** that depends on the **values** of `f` and `αβ1`, whatever they might be. If you want just a number, this invites chaos.

Comment: Hi John. Thanks! That clarifies a lot of thinks I have had previously trouble with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably best to re-write the question entirely.

As I now understand it (mis-understand it?) using the following definitions

```
re = 1/6 (2 fα1 - fα2 - fα3 + Sqrt[3] (-fβ2 + fβ3))
im = 1/6 (Sqrt[3] fα2 - Sqrt[3] fα3 + 2 fβ1 - fβ2 - fβ3)
cpx = re + I*im
```

As well as

```
fαβ1 = fα1 + I fβ1
(* fα1 + I fβ1 *)

fαβ2 = fα2 + I fβ2
(* fα2 + I fβ2 *)

fαβ3 = fα3 + I fβ3
(* fα3 + I fβ3 *)
```

You want to determine what `cpx` will be if the variables `fα1`, `fβ1`, `fα2` ...  are eliminated.

Two steps:

```
Eliminate[{cpx == re + I*im, 
           fαβ1 == fα1 + I fβ1, 
           fαβ2 == fα2 + I fβ2, 
           fαβ3 == fα3 + I fβ3},
  {fα1, fβ1, fα2,  fβ2, fα3, fβ3 }]
```

which produces

```
-I (6 I cpx + I fαβ2 + Sqrt[3] fαβ2 + I fαβ3 - Sqrt[3] fαβ3) == 2 fαβ1
```

so that those parameters have been successfully eliminated.

Now take the equality expression and solve for `cpx`

```
Solve[-I (6 I cpx + I fαβ2 + Sqrt[3] fαβ2 +
       I fαβ3 - Sqrt[3] fαβ3) == 2 fαβ1, cpx]
```

with the result

```
{{cpx -> 1/6 (2 fαβ1 - fαβ2 - fαβ3 + I (Sqrt[3] fαβ2 - Sqrt[3] fαβ3))}}
```

This does not match the result in your question but it is a valid answer.

We can validate it by using

```
Simplify[re + I im -
   (1/6 (2 fαβ1 - fαβ2 - fαβ3 + I (Sqrt[3] fαβ2 - Sqrt[3] fαβ3))) /.
   {fαβ1 -> fα1 + I fβ1, 
    fαβ2 -> fα2 + I fβ2, 
    fαβ3 -> fα3 + I fβ3} ]
```

In words we are comparing the original `cpx` with the result from `Solve` and using `ReplaceAll` (that is the shortcut "/.") to convert the compound expressions (e.g, `fαβ1`) into its real and imaginary components `fα1 + I fβ1`.

Comment: Thank you, I'll restrain myself from using subscripts. However, I might not ask the question correctly, so I am not sure you understand me.
I want Mathematica to produce me `cpx2` from `cpx` when I define that:
`fαβ1 = fα1 + I fβ1;
fαβ2 = fα2 + I fβ2;
fαβ3 = fα3 + I fβ;`

Comment: @Ivan Updated with my current understanding of your question.

Comment: I always get amazed how certain thing in Mathematica can be elegantly done.Thank you very much!
The answer is actually the one I was looking for, it is only in a different form, but that does not make any difference.By using your suggestion I came to this solution:
`Solve[Eliminate[{cpx==re+I*im,
fαβ1==fα1+I fβ1,
fαβ2==fα2+I fα2,
fαβ3==fα3+I fβ3},
{fα1,fβ1,fα2,fβ2,fα3,fβ3}],cpx][[1,1,2]]//FullSimplify`